# AOSP is taking Generic.kl file instead of customized keylayout file for remote key mapping

Tags: android, keymapping, infrared

For IR remote integration I have added my own *myKey.idc* and *myKey.kl* file in device folder. I have added keylayout file in *myKey.idc* as below:

```
keyboard.layout = myKey
```

But still android is taking `Generic.kl` file as keylayout map file.

Can anyone tell me why it is not taking my keylayout map file? Is there any other configuration file I need to change?

Note: I integrated androlirc with aosp oreo for remote keys. Got the codebase from [this](https://github.com/zokama/Androlirc).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the permissions to 644

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the issue was my keylayout file was invalid.  Android simply silently dropped it instead of reporting any error.  My issue was I was using a flag that was no longer supported on a more recent Android version.

I found you can validate your layout file with the validatekeymaps tool.

```
> make validatekeymaps
> validatekeymaps DEVICE_NAME.kl
```

After validating the file, the keymap was found and used intead of Generic.kl